# Beacon communication plugin in Flutter

Tags: dart, ibeacon, flutter, estimote

I am looking for plugins to communicate with beacons in Flutter, like CoreLocation and estimote SDK in iOS. I don't want to use native code integration in my application. Does Flutter provide any plugin for this purpose?

Comment: I'm looking exactly the same with advertising support. Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Google Flutter doesn't support Bluetooth. But you can check out this plugin: [FlutterBlue](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_blue)

> FlutterBlue is a bluetooth plugin for Flutter, a new mobile SDK to
> help developers build modern apps for iOS and Android.
>
> FlutterBlue aims to offer the most from both platforms (iOS and
> Android). Using the FlutterBlue instance, you can scan for and connect
> to nearby devices (BluetoothDevice). Once connected to a device, the
> BluetoothDevice object can discover services (BluetoothService),
> characteristics (BluetoothCharacteristic), and descriptors
> (BluetoothDescriptor). The BluetoothDevice object is then used to
> directly interact with characteristics and descriptors.